# LinearLayout.addView - The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android, android-layout

In my onCreate(), i have a code like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    newMethod();

    getSupportActionBar().hide();


}
```

this newMethod() function will call this function:

```
 private void setupScreen() {


    leftlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.leftlayout);
    if (leftlayout == null) {
        leftlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        leftlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        leftlayout.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL);
    }

    rightlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rightlayout);
    if (rightlayout == null) {
        rightlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        rightlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        rightlayout.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL);
    }

    mainlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
    if (mainlayout == null) {
        mainlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        mainlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        mainlayout.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL);
    }

    loadButtons(defaultChords);

    mainlayout.addView(leftlayout);

    mainlayout.addView(rightlayout);

    //this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    this.setContentView(mainlayout);
}
```

the error is based on this line : `mainlayout.addView(leftlayout);`.

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/guitarbody"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/k0" android:text="chord" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.29"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rightlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post the layout xml file

Comment: updated the question with XML file.

Answer (score 0):

```
    leftlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.leftlayout);
    if (leftlayout == null) {
      leftlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
      leftlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
      leftlayout.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL);
    }
```

Error means that you are adding a `view` as child which already has parent to another parent `layout`.
So, in the above code when the `if` condition is executed, which means whenever a new `Layout` is created at runtime, it will work fine because it does not have a parent. 
But when layout is created using `findViewById()` method, the created layout will already have a parent so error will be thrown

Even the root element of you layout xml file will be a child of system generated parent to which it will be attached

So the solution will be to always create the `view` at runtime and add it to parent layout

Remove `leftlayout` and `rightlayout` layouts from xml file then create and add those layout whenever needed

or try this

```
mainlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
if (mainlayout == null) {
    mainlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    mainlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    mainlayout.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL);
}

leftlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.leftlayout);
if (leftlayout == null) {
    leftlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    leftlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    leftlayout.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL);
    mainlayout.addView(leftlayout)
}

rightlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rightlayout);
if (rightlayout == null) {
    rightlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    rightlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    rightlayout.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL);
    mainlayout.addView(rightlayout)
}
this.setContentView(mainlayout);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how should I modified my code if i intent to keep it in this way?

Comment: as I have mentioned donot create view from layout. remove those lines where you create layouts using `findViewById()` method

Answer (score 0):

try this code in `onCreate()` of your activity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
LinearLayout Main_layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
//remove parent view first
((ViewGroup)Main_layout.getParent()).removeView(Main_layout);
newMethod();
```

Comment: this might work but not recommend because it will be like you are adding a view in xml file, then removing it in onCreate and then again creating the same view and setting to layout

Comment: Hi, i tried the code already, no errors were shown(i dont know), but! the the android studio execute the application to the device, the application never appear on the device screen

Comment: @JackPowell i don;t understand `application never appear on the device screen`??

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 which means the application never shown in the device screen after the android studio execute the application into device